# Calling a userform in Excel VBA and continue depending on which button was clicked

Tags: excel, vba, progress-bar, userform

I have four modules, three buttons and one userform, a progressbar, in my Excel workbook. I would like to show a progressbar during the runtime of all four modules.

Example:

I click on a button which executes the following code and makes my progressbar visible:

```
Private Sub GWPCClearDataButton_Click()

    ProgressBar.Show

End Sub
```

In my userform i have the following code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

    GWPCClearData

End Sub
```

This calls one of my four modules which works fine so far.

Now here's where I'm stuck.

Of course, I would like to use the same progressbar for all modules but how can I determine in the userform code block which button was clicked and then depending on that call another module?

Example:

```
Private Sub GWPCClearDataButton_Click()

    ProgressBar.Show

End Sub

Private Sub GSEPClearDataButton_Click()

    ProgressBar.Show

End Sub
```

UserForm:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

    If "BUTTON_NAME" = "GWPCClearDataButton" Then

        GWPCClearData

    ElseIf "BUTTON_NAME" = "GSEPClearDataButton" Then

        GSEPClearData

    End if

End Sub
```

How could I do that? I have yet to find a possibility to pass a parameter to my userform which would contain the button name.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: In your userform you could create a public variable and then save the button that called it into that? you could then read the variable to get the button that called it. To pass a varaible to a userform rather than using public variables you have to create a sub in the userform, Start_Up(var1 as string) then before you show the form run that sub and pass the button name

Comment: Maybe you could use **Public** variables and set it/them to specific values regarding which button you used!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form put

```
Sub Start_Form(Called_From as string)
    'Process Called_From as needed
End Sub
```

When you call your form just call the sub first like below

```
<form_name>.Start_Form "Button Called From"
<form_name>.Show
```

Basically you have to pass the variable via another sub(can be called anything) in the userform and then show the form after

---

User Form Code

```
Dim test

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
MsgBox test
End Sub

Sub start(tt)
test = tt
End Sub
```

Module code

```
Sub t()
UserForm1.start "Hello World!"
UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! I've added `Public Button As String` into my userform and then `Button = Called_From` into the `Start_Form` Sub.

After that, I was able to check the variable `Button` in the `UserForm_Activate()` Sub for the button name. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just a quick note. if you use the public variable you shouldnt need to use the Start_Form sub should be able to directly access it like <userform>.<variable>. Or you should be able to take the public out and use the Start_Form sub to add the variable. Public variables can get messy and if you dont HAVE to use them then its best practice to not use them

Comment: Oh okay. The thing is when I try it with `Dim Button As String` and `Button = Called_From` in the `Start_Form` Sub, the variable is empty in the `UserForm_Activate` Sub and thus the verification fails everytime. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I have added a small (small being a blank userform and no other real code lol), I hope that helps show you how you can not use a public variable to pass the value.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't realize I had to move `Dim Button As String` out of my sub. It works now!